# how to create finger print authorization in android?

Tags: android, authorization, fingerprint

I want to create password and finger print authorization for my app. I know how to do the password part but my question is how to create finger print authorization?

so, I have gone through the tutorial by androidHive and written this code:

```
public class LogUpInActivity extends Activity {
// sign up statue
private SharedPreferences StatuSharePreference;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor_state;
public boolean state_signUp, default_state, state_check;
private Stage mStage;

// sign up with password
private View signUpContent;
private EditText signUp_pasword_editText, signUp_conf_password_editText, signIn_password_editText;
public static SharedPreferences save_password_sharePreference;
public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor_password;
public static String logIn_password = null;

// sign in with password
public View signIn_passwordContent;
public int times_of_signIn = 5;

// sign in with finger print
private View signIn_fingerPrintContent;
private TextView msg_fingerPrint;
private KeyStore keyStore;
private Cipher cipher;
private static final String KEY_NAME = "mohrOmum";


// sign in after unlocking
public boolean sign_in_again;

private Button cancelBTN, stateBTN;
private TextView msg_state_conf;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_container);

    TextView who = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.who);
    who.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/mehr.ttf"));
    TextView signInPassTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password_description);
    signInPassTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/nazanin.ttf"));
    TextView signUpPassTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signUp_title);
    signUpPassTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/nazanin.ttf"));
    StatuSharePreference = getSharedPreferences("signUp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor_state = StatuSharePreference.edit();

    signUpContent = findViewById(R.id.signup_content);
    signUp_pasword_editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
    signUp_conf_password_editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.conf_pass);
    signIn_password_editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    msg_state_conf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notConfiration_msg);
    save_password_sharePreference = getSharedPreferences("password", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor_password = save_password_sharePreference.edit();


    signIn_passwordContent = findViewById(R.id.signIn_password_container);

    signIn_fingerPrintContent = findViewById(R.id.fingerprint_container);
    msg_fingerPrint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fingerprint_description);

    // Initializing both Android Keyguard Manager and Fingerprint Manager
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);

    // check if sign up is done or not
    if (!default_state) {
        state_signUp = false;
        default_state = true;
    } else {
        state_signUp = true;
    }

    state_check = StatuSharePreference.getBoolean("signUp", state_signUp);
    if (!state_check) {
        // register user password
        signIn_passwordContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        signUpContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mStage = Stage.SIGNUP;
    } else {
        signUpContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        signIn_passwordContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Check whether the device has a Fingerprint sensor.
        if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) {
            signIn_fingerPrintContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            signIn_fingerPrintContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Checks whether fingerprint permission is set on manifest
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                msg_fingerPrint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                msg_fingerPrint.setText(R.string.fingerPrint_not_avable);
                msg_fingerPrint.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_color));
            } else {
                // Check whether at least one fingerprint is registered
                if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
                    msg_fingerPrint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    msg_fingerPrint.setText(R.string.fingerPrint_not_register);
                    msg_fingerPrint.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_color));
                } else {
                    // Checks whether lock screen security is enabled or not
                    if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {
                        msg_fingerPrint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        msg_fingerPrint.setText(R.string.fingerPrint_not_register);
                        msg_fingerPrint.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_color));
                    } else {
                        generateKey();


                        if (cipherInit()) {
                            FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
                            FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
                            helper.startAuth(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        mStage = Stage.SIGNIN_PASSWORD;
    }


    cancelBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
    cancelBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    logIn_password = save_password_sharePreference.getString("password", logIn_password);
    stateBTN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.second_dialog_button);
    stateBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (mStage) {
                case SIGNUP: //get user password and register it
                    registerPassword();
                    break;
                /*case  SIGNIN_FINGERPRINT:// open sign in with password
                    signInWithPassword();
                    break;*/
                case SIGNIN_PASSWORD://checking passsword entry
                    verifyPassword();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });


} // on create

/**
 * get user password from Edit text , check its lengh , confirm it
 **/
public void registerPassword() {
    String passString = signUp_pasword_editText.getText().toString();
    String confPassString = signUp_conf_password_editText.getText().toString();

    if ((passString.equals(confPassString)) &&
            (passString.length() == 12) &&
            (confPassString.length() == 12)) {
        logIn_password = passString;
        editor_password.putString("password", logIn_password).commit();
        Toast.makeText(this, logIn_password, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        msg_state_conf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        msg_state_conf.setText(R.string.msg_conf);
        msg_state_conf.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_color));

        editor_state.putBoolean("signUp", true).commit();
        //state_signUp = true;

        //mina! ***checking fingerPrint sensor***
        /* + : finger primt authorization
        ** - : sign in with password
         */
        mStage = Stage.SIGNIN_PASSWORD;
        signUpContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        signIn_passwordContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        msg_state_conf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        msg_state_conf.setText(R.string.msg_not_conf);
        msg_state_conf.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_color));
        //not confirm
        editor_state.putBoolean("signUp", false).commit();

    }
}


/**
 * Checks whether the current entered password is correct, and dismisses the the dialog and
 * let's the activity know about the result.
 */
private void verifyPassword() {
    logIn_password = save_password_sharePreference.getString("signUp", logIn_password);
    Toast.makeText(this, logIn_password, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (signIn_password_editText.getText().toString().equals(logIn_password)) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LogUpInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        LogUpInActivity.this.finish();
    } else {
        --times_of_signIn;
        Toast.makeText(this, times_of_signIn + "تعداد ورود باقیمانده:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        signIn_password_editText.setText(null);

        if (times_of_signIn == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.restart_app, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            MainActivity.sqlDB.delete(DataBaseClass.BANK_TABLE_NAME, null, null);
            logIn_password = null;
            editor_password.putString("password", logIn_password).commit();
            state_signUp = false;
            editor_state.putBoolean("signUp", state_signUp).commit();
            signIn_passwordContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            signUpContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mStage = Stage.SIGNUP;
        }
    }

}



/*
sign in with finger print
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
protected void generateKey() {
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
    try {
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
        //startActivity(new Intent(LogUpInActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
    }


    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        keyGenerator.init(new
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(
                        KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
            | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public boolean cipherInit() {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/" + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/" + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return true;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}


public void onFinish(){
    editor_password.putString("password",logIn_password).commit();

}




/**
 * Enumeration to indicate which authentication method the user is trying to authenticate with.
 */
public enum Stage {
    SIGNUP,
    SIGNIN_FINGERPRINT,
    SIGNIN_PASSWORD
}
```

Now after all this I have the following questions:

1. How can i set Intent after finger print authorization?
2. How can i time-limited for finger print authorization (as `verifyPassword()` method)

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

In `FingerPrintHamdler` class, you can find `onAuthenticationSucceeded()` method. so write this code:

```
public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
    this.update("Fingerprint Authentication succeeded.", true);
    Intent intent=new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```